# Coding graphical progress bar in php (overlay issue)

Tags: php, gd

[image]

So far I have the background working, and I have the `%` bubble floating on top of the bar working. Everything went smoothly using the PHP/GD functions.

But I can't figure out how to add the yellow part. I mean, I could overlay solid color easily. But how would I go in showing that progress bar with vertical stripes, gradients, rounded border and inner shadows?

Comment: Thats not php, you need css and html for design.

Comment: I'd like to do it with php/GD with css/jquery it is trivial.

Comment: You *can't* do it in PHP.

Comment: You have to use jquery, it is very simple, I will create an example for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I found an example using `php`, `javascript`, and `html` [here](http://w3shaman.com/article/php-progress-bar-script), you can also use the jquery implementation [here](http://w3shaman.com/article/php-progress-bar-script). And here is a simple one I made in `html` and `css` [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VhRtC/) .

#### Edit

Actually, there is a way.

`PHP/GD`

PHP Code

```
<?php  
// set the type of data (Content-Type) to PNG image  
header("Content-Type: image/png");  

// extract GET global array  
extract($_GET);  

// set defaults  
if(! isset($max)) $max = 100;  
if(! isset($val)) $val = 100;  

// this method prepare blank true color image with given width and height  
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 20);  

// set background color (light-blue)  
$c_bg = imagecolorallocate($im, 222, 236, 247);  
// set foreground color (dark-blue)  
$c_fg = imagecolorallocate($im, 27, 120, 179);  

// calculate the width of bar indicator  
$val_w = round(($val * 397) / $max);  

// create a rectangle for background and append to the image  
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 400, 20, $c_bg);  
// create a rectangle for the indicator and appent to the image  
imagefilledrectangle($im, 2, 2, $val_w, 17, $c_fg);  

// render the image as a PNG  
imagepng($im);  

// finally destroy image resources  
imagedestroy($im);  
?>
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
<head>  
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />  
<title>PHP GD-Progress Bar</title>  
</head>  

<body>  

    <img src="progressbar.php?max=100&val=70" />  

</body>  

</html>
```

Comment: Yes I know :) I've already written that part. Essentially my question is how to draw gradients and such using GD.

Comment: @SandroDzneladze Can you post a link to your script?

Comment: I went jquery way, it turns out it is quite complicated to manipulate graphics with GD in this way. I had to install imagemagick. In face of all difficulties jquery seemed the easiest option. So I accept your answer :) thanks!.

Comment: Great answer, your example has helped me a lot. Thanks.